# Why is Vagrant up failing on yajl and librarian-chef?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, yajl, librarian

When I attempt to bring up vagrant I get this error

```
$ vagrant up --provision

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
/Users/username/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1/lib/yajl/yajl.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [universal.x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.
```

I am running OS X 10.10 and ruby 2.0.0-p594

Comment: I have checked the logs and they are all blank.

Comment: paste the content in `Vagrantfile` and `Cheffile`, second, manually run `Librarian-Chef install`, any error message?